# php symfony dom crawler find all rss links

Tags: php, regex, symfony, rss

I am using Symfony Dom Crawler for html parsing and I need to find out all rss links on different html pages. These links look different, for example:

```
<a href="logical/footer/news.rss" class="footer__link">RSS</a>
```

or

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"  href="rss/all">
```

or

```
<li href="rss/rss.xml">some text</li>
```

etc...
As for the second example I can get the link hooking to the link type (application/rss+xml) but this does not work with the first or third example. I have already tried the following:

```
$crawler->filter('a[href='.preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z\"\'\/.]+.xml\"/uis', $text).']')
```

but it did not work unfortunately. Maybe there is a way to filter all elements containing a particular text, RSS for example? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Start to look at the symfony dom crawler documentation to see what kind of parameter is needed for the different methods. You can look for `preg_match_all` in the PHP manual to see what this function returns. I think the best (easiest) way to achieve what you want is to use XPath with the `filterXPath` method.

Comment: Obviously you can also use the build-in DOMXPath class instead of the symfony dom crawler componant.

Comment: Could you please any example how to use these methods. Is it possible to filter a node based on the text inside it? Or based on a string, containing in node href (some kind of rss.xml inside href)?